# Cast to Boolean failed for value "on" path "sell"

Tags: javascript, node.js

Currently I'm having this strange error this have never happened to me before. When I post a form with checked checkbox "sale" I get this error `Cast to Boolean failed for value "on" path "sell"`
This is the schema part from model:

```
    sell: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
    },
```

This is how I request the checkbox:

```
sell: req.body.sell
```

And then I save everything but I get that error. Maybe there's better logic than this to check if checkbox was checked ?

Comment: A checkbox's value, when not specified, will be submitted as "on" or nothing when submitted - not 1 or 0 (hence, not a boolean).

Comment: @Lewis strange. When I was programming like half year ago it was working probably something changed. So I leave it blank and now it works and yes I get "on" or nothing. Thank you

Comment: No worries. I believe what is submitted when no value is specified is browser dependent. Your best bet is to always specify a value and check for that.